# AWS Glacier US East is cheapest. Any drawbacks if I use that to store data from India?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I am from India and I have some data that I want to store in AWS Glacier **Deep Archive**. From the current pricing sheet I see [here](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/), I see that Asia Pacific (Mumbai) costs around $0.002 whereas US East (N. Virginia) costs $0.00099 per GB per month.

So that means, if I store data in the US, it would cost me HALF of the amount that I would pay to store the data locally.

Suppose I have 1 TB of data that I need to store. In Mumbai, it would cost me $0.002 x 1000 = $2 per month. That's $24/yr and $480 for 20 years. The same would cost me $240 (half) over 20 years. So that's like saving $240 over 20 years or $1 a month.

Now that's pretty small for an individual user, but for a small/medium sized company, that's straight 50% savings.

Now I do understand that storing data closer to you is better etc., but my question is, assuming you already have an offsite backup and you are storing data in the cloud only for peace of mind,  - Is there anything else that I should watch out for if I store data in the US ? Is there ANY difference (apart from the pricing of services) between these two regions ?

Comment: You will have to pay cross-region network transfer costs to get the data there, doubt that will be worth it.

Comment: @jordanm - Thank you for answering. How will it cost more ? I am not moving any data from one region to another. I am directly uploading to US east via Internet. I am not able to find any charges wrt "cross-region network transfer" - unless it is VPC or moving data from one region to another. Do you have any documentation for this ?

Comment: @Shrinath Where is the data coming _from_? Are you sending the data from your own computer/data center, or is it coming from somewhere in AWS?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - I have the data in my personal laptop and I plan to upload it to AWS Glacier via the internet. Basically just a bunch of photos and videos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference with the service between regions. You can certainly store your data in the USA to take advantage of the lower price.

The only downside will be slower data transfer, but that's fine for backup purposes.

You can either upload directly into `Glacier Deep Archive` storage class, or use a Lifecycle Rule to move the objects to that storage class.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Good to hear that from a Tech Evangelist working at AWS itself :)

Comment: And yes, my plan is to use the AWS Glacier API to upload directly to the Deep Archive storage class.

Comment: Please note that the Glacier Deep Archive storage class is only available via Amazon S3. Therefore, you should upload to S3 using the Amazon S3 API rather than the "AWS Glacier" API.

Comment: Thank you. That was helpful. I was struggling to find a way to set the storage class in the Glacier API and SDK. So does that mean that I have to create an S3 bucket and not a Glacier vault ? And then to upload data to the S3 bucket, I have two options - using AWS console and set the storage class as Deep Archive OR directly upload to Deep Archive class using S3 CLI. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes. A third way is to use a Lifecycle Policy to change the storage class automatically after _x_ days. Using Glacier via S3 is much easier than using Glacier directly. It removes the pain of low-level API calls.

Comment: Ok. Using the third way would mean I would have to pay for standard storage for x days. I am comfortable with the CLI, so I'll directly upload to deep archive using S3 API. Thanks again !